# Is Wolfram Alpha correct?

Tags: derivatives, wolfram-alpha

Given the attempted derivative at http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%28a%28x%29+choose+b%28x%29%29%2Fdx, I believe the result from Wolfram Alpha is off by a factor of 2 or, at least I get a result equal to twice as much WA does when I distribute `du/dx` and `dv/dx` thru their respective terms. Where did I go wrong?

Note: The `u` and `v` come into play when using the chain rule, as seen in the step-by-step solution. Also, `a` and `b` are continuous functions.

Comment: Please clarify, there doesn't appear to be any $u$ or $v$ in this problem.

Comment: What are a and b?

Comment: @vadim123: clarified.

Comment: @sizz: Continuous functions. I just made an edit to clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, here are WolframAlpha's steps:

[image]

Ultimately, it's just a matter of applying the multi-variate chain rule (shown in the WA output) together with the fact that the partial derivatives of the binomial can be expressed in terms of the digamma function.  Specifically:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \binom{x}{y}=\binom{x}{y} (\psi ^{(0)}(x+1)-\psi^{(0)}(x-y+1))$$

and

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\binom{x}{y}=\binom{x}{y} (\psi ^{(0)}(x-y+1)-\psi^{(0)}(y+1)).$$

Comment: Interesting, I received something distinctly different from WA: http://i.imgur.com/54RwEUQ.png I wonder why.

Comment: @xuinkrbin. At a glance, I do see some formatting differences, but nothing major.  And the answers appear to be the same.  Do you see anything *mathematically* different between the two?  (Again, I looked just quickly and it's pretty late for me.)  As to the differences that are there, I'm sure that's due to the fact that I accessed the steps through Mathematica; it looks like you went through the website.

Comment: Yes, I used the site. Mathematically different? Well, *if* We were to presume the first equation after "Using the chain rule" were correct, One can show the result must actually be 2x what WA gave. At the same time, said first equation appears to be wrong when compared to the steps You posted and I am inclined to go with Yours. Thanks!